# Progress Bar styles

Tags: android, android-layout, android-styles, android-progressbar

What is the difference between the below two style references?

```
    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progress"
        style="?attr/progressBarStyle"

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progress"
        style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`?attr/progressBarStyle` refers to style `progressBarStyle` as defined in the current theme.

`@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar` refers to style `Widget.ProgressBar` (which might be a style `ProgressBar` that has `Widget` as parent) as defined in the android sdk.

Comment: Thank you for sharing the knowledge. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progress"
    style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar"
```

This style is a style of android.

```
<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progress"
    style="?attr/progressBarStyle"
```

It seems your reference is wrong. But I think it is a custom style.